# data class empty constructor for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

```
data class MainPosts(val context: Context, val posts: Posts, val livePost: LivePosts?)
{
    constructor() : this(null!!, null!!, null!!) 
}
```

Hey, I've been trying to figure out how to create an empty constructor on data class for Firebase.

I tried that code which is above but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a default constructor, you should initialize the values:

```
data class MainPosts(
    val context: Context = someDefaultValue1, 
    val posts: Posts = someDefaultValue2, 
    val livePost: LivePosts? = null)
```

If they are all nullable as it seems from your constructor code:

```
data class MainPosts(
    val context: Context? = null, 
    val posts: Posts? = null, 
    val livePost: LivePosts? = null)
```

This give you a default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Nice answers already suggested. However, another way to go is to use the no-args compiler plugin which generates a synthetic no argument constructor. 
It's specifically designed for such situations where providing default parameters might not be desirable.

Checkout [No-arg compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

In this way constructor is presented:

```
data class MainPosts(val context: Context?=null, val posts: Posts?=null, val livePost: LivePosts?=null)
```